# Exception in defer callback: Error: No such template: wiki

Tags: javascript, meteor

I created a Meteor package called Wiki.

Inside the package I have a **wiki.html** where which contains

```
<template name="wiki">
FULL WIKI UI CODE HERE
</template>
```

Then I have a **wiki.js** where I declared my collections and events. However, inside my **wiki.js** I got an error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined
>
> Exception in defer callback: Error: No such template: wiki

I do not understand because I already have wiki template. Inside my **package.js** I have this:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.use('templating', 'client');
  api.use('easy:search', 'client');
  api.use('templates:tabs', 'client');
  api.use('blaze-html-templates', 'client');
  api.addFiles('wiki.js', 'client');
  api.addFiles('wiki.html', 'client');
  api.addFiles('wikiserver.js', 'server');
});
```

Am I missing something why template wiki can not be detected? However, if I remove all the codes inside my JS file, everything works fine. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add wiki.html before wiki.js

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.use('templating', 'client');
  api.use('easy:search', 'client');
  api.use('templates:tabs', 'client');
  api.use('blaze-html-templates', 'client');
  api.addFiles('wiki.html', 'client');
  api.addFiles('wiki.js', 'client');
  api.addFiles('wikiserver.js', 'server');
});
```